# Golang Non-Struct Type Pointer Receiver

Tags: go

I created a custom type based on the Golang [`net.IP`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#IP) type. What surprised me is that a method declared with a pointer receiver to my custom type can't modify the value to which the receiver points.

The `u` variable in this code snippet remains `nil` after calling `u.defaultIP()`. The IP can be modified if I changed my custom type to a struct with an IP field and the method is defined with a pointer receiver to the struct. What am I missing? Executable example can be found [here](https://play.golang.org/p/QZhx4XqOHt).

```
type userIP net.IP

func main() {
  var u *userIP
  u.defaultIP()
  fmt.Printf("%v\n", u) 
}

func (u *userIP) defaultIP() {
  defaultIP := userIP("127.0.0.1")
  u = &defaultIP
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to dereference the `u` before setting it's value.

From your example, change

```
defaultIP := userIP("127.0.0.1")
u = &defaultIP
```

to

```
*u = userIP("127.0.0.1")
```

For your example updated and working: https://play.golang.org/p/ycCLT0ed9F

Comment: dereference* (I tried editing this but it didn't allow me since the change was less than 6 characters)

Comment: The reader needs to click on a link to understand this answer.  (unless you already know what dereference means, but even so, how do you do that in golang—click on the link to find out :D

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: The pointer receiver needs to be dereferenced before it's value can be set. This applies to both struct and non-struct types. In the case of struct types, the dereferencing is automatically done by the selector expression.

After digging around a bit further, I think this behaviour is caused by the fact that the pointer receiver is not the same pointer calling the method.

Running this code snippet shows that the `u` pointer in the `main()` function is different from that in the `defaultIP()` method. Essentially, I end up **only** modifying the `u` pointer in the `defaultIP()` method. Executable example can be found [here](https://play.golang.org/p/bjNWbNdTjg).

```
func main() {
  var u *userIP         
  u.defaultIP()

  fmt.Printf("main(): address of pointer is %v\n", &u)
  fmt.Printf("main(): user IP address is %v\n", u)
}

type userIP net.IP

func (u *userIP) defaultIP() {  
  defaultIP := userIP("127.0.0.1")
  u = &defaultIP

  fmt.Printf("defaultIP(): address of pointer is %v\n", &u)
  fmt.Printf("defaultIP(): user IP address is %s\n", *u)
}
```

The correct way to do this is as pointed in Tom's answer i.e. dereference `u` in the `defaultIP()` method.

What puzzled me earlier was why would this example work if I wrapped the IP as a field in the struct? Running the code snippet shows that the two `u` pointers are indeed different, but the `ip` field is modified. Executable example can be found [here](https://play.golang.org/p/bCDrb2FAH5).

```
func main() {
  u := &userInfo{}
  u.defaultIP()

  fmt.Printf("main(): address of pointer is %v\n", &u)
  fmt.Printf("main(): user IP address is %s\n", u.ip)
}

type userInfo struct{
  ip net.IP
}

func (u *userInfo) defaultIP() {
  u.ip = net.ParseIP("127.0.0.1")
  fmt.Printf("defaultIP(): address of pointer is %v\n", &u)
  fmt.Printf("defaultIP(): user IP address is %s\n", u.ip)
}
```

Turns out that this is caused by the [selector expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors) (`x.y`). To quote the doc,

> Selectors automatically dereference pointers to structs. If x is a pointer to a struct,  x.y is shorthand for (*x).y; if the field y is also a pointer to a struct, x.y.z is shorthand for (*(*x).y).z, and so on. If x contains an anonymous field of type *A, where  A is also a struct type, x.f is a shortcut for (*x.A).f.

So in my case, the `u.ip` expression dereferences `u` before modifying the `ip` field, which essentially translates to`(*u).ip`.

Answer (score 0):

Two Options:

1- With dereferencing: like this working code and using `net.ParseIP("127.0.0.1")`
([The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/qbVIFjCY7j)):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

type userIP net.IP

func main() {
    var u userIP
    u.defaultIP()
    fmt.Println(u)
}

func (u *userIP) defaultIP() {
    *u = userIP(net.ParseIP("127.0.0.1"))
}
```

output:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 255 255 127 0 0 1]
```

---

2- Without dereferencing ([The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/QLTX0iR3Jr)):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

type userIP net.IP

func main() {
    u := make(userIP, 4)
    u.defaultIP()
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", u)
}

func (u userIP) defaultIP() {
    u[0], u[1], u[2], u[3] = 127, 0, 0, 1
}
```

---

And note that `net.IP` is `[]byte`, see `net.IP` Docs:

> An IP is a single IP address, a slice of bytes. Functions in this
>   package accept either 4-byte (IPv4) or 16-byte (IPv6) slices as input.

Comment: Using `u = &defaultIP` is my problem. Without the dereferenced `*u`, `userIP{127, 0, 0, 1}` won't work.

Comment: `userIP("127.0.0.1")` is fine. Refer Tom's answer at https://play.golang.org/p/ycCLT0ed9F.

Comment: @isim You may use `net.ParseIP("127.0.0.1")`  or `userIP{127, 0, 0, 1}`